# GoogleMapsAPIで位置情報を別ファイル(JSON)データに分ける

Tags: javascript, google-maps

GoogleMapで位置情報と情報ウィンドウの内容が入ったJSONデータに連動してマーカーをクリックすると情報ウィンドウが表示され、コンテンツ表示させるものを作成しているのですが作ったコードではマーカーが消滅しています。javascript内に位置情報を配列として入力したものは正しく動きました。ご教授お願いいたします。

javascript内に配列を入れたもの

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var currentWindow = null ;
  function initialize() {

    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
    $("#map").css('height',bodyHeight);

      var myOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.6954806, 139.76325010000005),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
      var markers = [
      ['TAM 東京', 35.6954806, 139.76325010000005,'コメントA'],
      ['小川町駅', 35.6951212, 139.76610649999998,'コメントB'],
      ['淡路町駅', 35.69496, 139.76746000000003,'コメントC'],
      ['御茶ノ水駅', 35.6993529, 139.76526949999993,'コメントD'],
      ['神保町駅', 35.695932, 139.75762699999996,'コメントE'],
      ['新御茶ノ水駅', 35.696932, 139.76543200000003,'コメントF']
      ];
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i][0];
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1],markers[i][2]);
          var comment = markers[i][3];
          createMarker(name, latlng, comment, map);
      }
  }
  function createMarker(name, latlng, comment, map) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (currentWindow) {
              currentWindow.close();
          }
          infoWindow.setContent(
            '<div class="infoWindow">'+
            '<h2>'+name+'</h2>'+
            '<p>'+comment+'</p>'+
            '</div>'
          );
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          currentWindow = infoWindow;
      });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div data-role="page" id="top">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>DEMO</h1>
   </div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#sub" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown">ダイアログを表示 &raquo;</a>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
  <h1>DEMO</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="sub" data-close-btn="right">
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1>タイトル</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>コメントはここから始まります</p>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">閉じる</a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#infoWindow{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

位置情報を別データ(JSON)に分けたコード

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var currentWindow = null ;
$(function() {
$.getJSON("maps.json", function(markers){
  var setno = markers.length;
  var title = new Array();
  var lat = new Array();
  var lng = new Array();
  var text = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    title[i] = markers[i][0];
    lat[i] = markers[i][1];
    lng[i] = markers[i][2];
    text[i] = markers[i][3];
 }
 initialize(setno, title, lat, lng, text);
 });
 });
 function initialize(setno, title, lat, lng, text) {

 var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
 $("#map").css('height',bodyHeight);

  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.6954806, 139.76325010000005),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = title[i];
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
      var comment = text[i];
      createMarker(name, latlng, comment, map);
  }
  }
  function createMarker(name, latlng, comment, map) {
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (currentWindow) {
          currentWindow.close();
      }
      infoWindow.setContent(
        '<div class="infoWindow">'+
        '<h2>'+name+'</h2>'+
        '<p>'+comment+'</p>'+
        '</div>'
      );
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      currentWindow = infoWindow;
   });
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
   </head>

   <body onload="initialize()">
   <div data-role="page" id="top">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>DEMO</h1>
   </div>
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
   <a href="#sub" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown">ダイアログを表示 &raquo;</a>
   <div id="map"></div>
   </div>

   <div data-role="footer">
   <h1>DEMO</h1>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div data-role="page" id="sub" data-close-btn="right">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>タイトル</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
   <p>コメントはここから始まります</p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">閉じる</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </body>

   <style type="text/css">
   #map {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }

   #infoWindow{
   width: 300px;
   height: 400px;
   }
   </style>
```

maps.json

```
[
  ["TAM 東京", "35.6954806", "139.76325010000005","コメントA"],
  ["小川町駅", "35.6951212", "139.76610649999998","コメントB"],
  ["淡路町駅", "35.69496", "139.76746000000003","コメントC"],
  ["御茶ノ水駅", "35.6993529", "139.76526949999993","コメントD"],
  ["神保町駅", "35.695932", "139.75762699999996","コメントE"],
  ["新御茶ノ水駅", "35.696932", "139.76543200000003","コメントF"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`initialize`を実行しすぎです。
スクリプト内の
`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`
とHTML内の
`<body onload="initialize()">`
の`onload="initialize()"`が不要です。`initialize`は引数無しで実行されるとマーカーの無いマップを生成してしまいます。
`maps.json`を取得したら一回だけ実行すればよいです。

さらに`initialize`関数自体にもバグがあります。for文のループ条件で`markers.length`を参照していますが、これはこの関数内で未定義です。引数`setno`に配列の長さを渡してますのでそれを使ってください。

Comment: 記述されたことを通りに実行したところ正しくできました。
ありがとうございます